# Primitive root and quadratic residue modulo p

Tags: number-theory

> Let p be an odd prime and let g be a primitive root modulo p.
> Prove that if $g^k$ is a quadratic residue modulo p
> then  $(\frac{g^k}{p})=(-1)^k$

My attempt:
$(\frac{g^k}{p})=(\frac{g}{p})(\frac{g}{p})(\frac{g}{p})(\frac{g}{p})...(\frac{g}{p})$ but I am stuck with to show $(\frac{g}{p}) = -1$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Can we say anything about whether $k$ is even or odd?

Comment: If $g^k$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, doesn't that mean $(\frac{g^k}{p})=1$? Is the statement just saying "prove that $k$ is even" in a very roundabout way?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $g$ is a generator of a (multiplicative) cyclic group of even order. Why can't it be a square?

Answer (score -1):

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ be primitive and suppose on the contrary that $(\frac{n}{p})=1$. Then there exists an $m$ such that $n\equiv m^2\mod p$. Since $n$ is primitive, there is a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^k\equiv m\mod p$. Thus $n^{2k-1}\equiv 1\mod p$, which implies $$p-1=\text{ord}(n)\mid (2k-1).$$

But $p-1$ is even and $2k-1$ is odd, a contradiction. Thus $(\frac{n}{p})=-1$.